# 'photoanalysisd' running constantly on Catalina, even though I do not use Photos.app

Tags: catalina, photos.app, daemons

I recently upgraded from Mac OS Mojave to Catalina. The other day, I noticed that a process called **photoanalysisd** has been running constantly at nearly 100% CPU usage for various consecutive days. It doesn't cause fans to spin loudly, but it still creates a noticeable heat on my Macbook.

What I find odd about this is that I actually do not use the Photos.app at all. I am a photographer, and I use Adobe Lightroom. All my photos are stored on an external HD which isn't normally connected to my Macbook. The Lightroom library, however, is stored on my internal SSD. There is of course also a Photos library on my internal SSD, but since I never imported anything to Photos.app, the Photos library is completely empty. This is what actually makes me wonder why the **photoanalysisd** process is running all the time.

I have already tried deleting the Photos Library on my SSD and have the Photos.app create a new one, but to no avail.

Does anyone know why **photoanalysisd** is running all the time, and if there is anything I can do to stop it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Weirdly enough, one of the suggestions in the 'what is photoanalysisd ...' question (linked) actually seems to have helped. I had Mac OS configured to share contacts with a Microsoft Exchange account I use for work. Once I stopped sharing contacts with MS Exchange, the daemon stopped.

I find this a bit weird as I don't see the link between the Photos app and Contacts, and it's also a bit of a bummer as I've now lost access to the Exchange contacts in Mail. But at least photoanalysisd now doesn't have a high CPU usage anymore.